# I have an issue with i18n and custom error handling in Django

Tags: python, django

I am implementing custom error handling in Django, and I have an issue with the `'404 Not Found'` error. Essentially, when I access `http://localhost:8000`, I am redirected to the 404 error page. However, if I type `http://localhost:8000/en/`, I am redirected to the homepage. What I want to achieve is to be redirected to the homepage even by simply typing `http://localhost:8000`.
In the main urls.py I've defined the urlpatterns in the following way:

`urlpatters = i18n_patterns( ... )`

and

`handler404 = "baseApp.views.error_404"`

Do you have any suggestion?

I tried changing LANGUAGE_CODE from "en-us" to "en" but it didn't work

Comment: I am facing the same issue.